# WebView with google analytics

Tags: webview, google-analytics

I have an app showing a website that I previously used an external app to open the link within the app

But I worked on updating the application so that it opens the application in the form of a web view

Here, Google statistics differed radically after the update, as 80% of visits are to the first page only of Web View.

And very few people browse the rest of the pages of the site. Is this normal because Web View does not display the page address in the interface, unlike a regular browser?

Or is there a problem